# Need to change Advanced custom Fields image to a gallery - Timber/Twig

Tags: wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I'm trying to make a change to my company website. An image gets pulled into the product page but I want to change it to a gallery. I have made the change in the ACF on the backend and loaded the images into the product page but nothing shows up on the product page front end.

I know i need to make a change to the template but i've never used timber/twig before and I'm having trouble finding where the image was originally added to the page in the code. There doesn't seem to a standard template as everything seems to be pulled in separately.

I found this in the twig files, which looks promising but, i'm assuming there is more that i am missing:

```
  <div class="image">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ post.meta('product_image').url }}" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
```